# Preview image before return intent ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-gallery

In my application i want to open the gallery and choose an image from it. So i do

```
gallery.setOnClickListener {
            val imageIntent = Intent().apply {
                type = "image/*"
                action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
            }
            startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(imageIntent, "Select an image"), IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        }
```

However, when i choose an image i want the user to be able to preview the image that he selected before i get it in the ActivityResult. In some devices and some apps (Google Photos) they do this by default, but in other devices i can't get that feature.
How can i have this functionality by default in every device?

Comment: How does the user select an image without a preview?

Comment: I mean when he selects the image from the "gridLayout" of the image show application (Gallery, Google Photos...) i want to see the image in full preview before the intent returns. Sometimes this happens,...sometimes it does not!

Comment: Google Photos does not show a detail view here.

Comment: Is there a way to have this always? Perhaps i could change the intent chooser and do a default intent. But is there an action or extra i could put to force this?

Comment: Dont know. Dont think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i have this functionality by default in every device?

You can't.

You are starting an activity from a third-party app. What the third-party app does is up to the developers of the third-party app.

In some cases, there are `Intent` extras that provide hints as to what we want the third-party app to do. In this case, there is no standard "please provide a full-screen preview" extra. And, even if there were, there is no requirement for any given `ACTION_PICK` activity to pay attention to that extra.